# Design changes in our site

Tags: support, design

Stack Overflow gets new design. How can we get such design to our site? Is that some that our mods need to import or it will be done by SO Team or do we need to request for such designs?

Comment: Why is this off-topic at all? Child Metas can also discuss and ask support questions about design and features. That is the reason they have Meta. Not everything is discussed on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 9):

### New design and theme is now Live.

If you mean the "left navigation bar" by design,  See [Live: Left nav, new theming and responsiveness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/357396)

You can check or uncheck the left navigation bar by going to your [user preferences](/users/preferences/current) and check "Hide Left Navigation". THe options will move to a drop down menu after doing that.

There will be no change in the theme and design as long as the site is in beta. There will be just default "white and blue" design. New changes in the design only applies when the site graduates. Designers from the Stack Overflow will post an update on our meta site and ask for opinions about our own theme when that happens.

Comment: So is it something like that we have to request or they will do it directly?

Comment: Can we add our custom design as well?

Comment: @TheDictator It is will be rolled out by the end of september. For now, it is only on SO and MSE. There are still many issues with it. They are still testing it. We will get special theme and design after we graduate.